# Correspondence between Serre and Tate on resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am told that there is a 1961 correspondence between J-P. Serre and J. Tate on resolution of singularities in characteristic 0, where Serre discusses his attempts to disprove the latter using R. Thom's obstructions to realizing a homology class as a manifold. Of course, as fate would have it, Hironaka solved this shortly after in his 1963 thesis.

More detail: *resolution of singularities* asks if the singularties of a singular algebraic variety can be resolved by blow up, and as result one has that homology classes can be represented by submanifolds. On the other hand, Thom showed that there is an obstruction to the latter for complex manifolds, but Hironaka's work shows that there is no obstruction if the manifold is also a complex algebraic variety.

Is there somewhere I can find a reference to this?

Comment: I recommend asking Dennis.

Comment: Funny story—he asked me to look this up, and I tried but haven't found it yet on my own.

Comment: Yes, I saw him this evening, and he told me about this.  There is a publication forthcoming of the Serre-Tate correspondence: <http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=smfdm-13>.

Comment: Ah, I see. This means it doesn't exist just yet but he knows about it. Thanks!

Comment: The Serre-Tate correspondence is already published. There is indeed a letter (october 1961) in which Serre asks whether quotients of vector spaces by linear actions of finite groups could provide counter-examples to resolution of singularities. A few months later (april 1962), they discuss Hironaka's proof that has just been announced.